# Generating random string based on regular expression in C# and Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, nuget

I am new to Unity and my requirement is to generate a random string based on regular expression in C#. My code is working well in Console Application, however, I am getting error for Fare namespace in UnityEditor. I explored on Internet and different forums, however, I didn't found any solution. Below is my code.

```
string GenerateString()
{
    string pattern = "^x[a2]{9,15}";
    var xeger = new Xeger(pattern);
    string generatedString = xeger.Generate();
    generatedString = xeger.Generate();
    return generatedString;
}
```

The error I am getting in UnityEditor is as follows;

**Assets\Scripts\PlayerController.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Fare' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I have tried the solution provided [here](https://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/unity-and-nuget/) for Nuget packages and Unity errors. The solution provided [here](https://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/unity-and-nuget/) works fine for "Fare" namespace however, **UnityEngine.UI** starts problem and visual studio shows that this namespace is not installed. Furthermore, I have tried to install NugetForUnity it didn't work too.

**My Requirement is:**
Generate random collectibles and each collectible should have a randomly generated string with length ranging from 9 to 15 characters using 3 alphabets. The first alphabet should be x. The second and third one should be derived from your first name and registration number – the first letter of the first name and last digit of your registration number. E.g. If my name is Abcd and my registration number is AB20-12786, then alphabets for my strings would be (x, a, 6).

**Any other suggestion will be highly appreciated for string generation for the above requirement. Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: In your code snippet you are not using any `Fare` (or is that where `Xeger` comes from which I also don't know) ... could you show your complete code?

Comment: @derHugo Xeger comes from Fare. I am sorry I didn't add full code. I have just added that function which generates random string.

Comment: So you say `using Fare;` .. is this a library you imported into your project?

Comment: Yes, this is a library and I have imported it in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that library `Fare` or how exactly you imported it into your project.

---

However, if I understand your underlying problem correctly what you want is

- one fix "alphabet" that only contains `'x'`
- one "alphabet" that only contains the first character of a name
- one "alphabet" that only contains the last digit of a certain string/number

I say "alphabet" because the way you describe it each of your "alphabets" anyway only seems to contain exactly **one single** character.

- Then build a new string with length between 9 and 15 and randomly taking one of the 3 given characters

So something like

```
private System.Random random = new System.Random();

string GenerateString(string name, string number)
{
    // Get you 3 available "alphabets" or better said single characters
    var availableCharacters = new char[3];
    availableCharacters[0] = 'x';
    // Get first char of name
    availableCharacters[1] = name[0];
    // Get last char of number
    availableCharacters[2] = number[number.Length-1];

    // Create a char array with random length between 9 and 15
    // NOTE that the last parameter of Random.Next is EXCLUSIVE
    var randomChars = new char[random.Next(9, 16)];
    // Then fill it with randomly picked characters from availableCharacters
    for(var i = 0; i < randomChars.Length; i++)
    {
        // pick random value from the given 3 chars
        // again NOTE that the last parameter of Random.Next is EXCLUSIVE
        randomChars[i] = availableCharacters[random.Next(0, availableCharacters.Length)];
    }
    
    // Finaly convert that random char array into your output string
    return new string(randomChars);
}
```

---

**Edit**

now that we know that `x` should always be the first character and then not used anymore:

```
private System.Random random = new System.Random();

string GenerateString(string name, string number)
{
    // Get you 2 available "alphabets" or better said single characters
    var availableCharacters = new char[2];
    // Get first char of name
    availableCharacters[0] = name[0];
    // Get last char of number
    availableCharacters[1] = number[number.Length-1];

    // Create a char array with random length between 9 and 15
    // NOTE that the last parameter of Random.Next is EXCLUSIVE
    var randomChars = new char[random.Next(9, 16)];
    // Fill in the first fix character x
    randomChars[0] = 'x';
    // Then fill the rest with randomly picked characters from availableCharacters
    // NOTE that we are starting the loop at index 1 this time since we already filled 0 with x
    for(var i = 1; i < randomChars.Length; i++)
    {
        // pick random value from the given 2 chars
        // again NOTE that the last parameter of Random.Next is EXCLUSIVE
        randomChars[i] = availableCharacters[random.Next(0, availableCharacters.Length)];
    }
    
    // Finaly convert that random char array into your output string
    return new string(randomChars);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @derHugo for your cooperation. Everything is working perfectly however, "Alphabet" "x" must come in the start only after that combination of only two characters should come.

Comment: you said your alphabets would be `x, a, 6` .. you didn't mention that `x` should anyway only be the first character ... you can simply hardcode it then ;) ... See the update at the bottom

Comment: One more problem with your code is that in a loop of 5 iterations for the first two iterations it generates random string however, string generated in 3rd, 4th and 5th iteration is equal to the string generated in 2nd iteration.

Comment: What do you mean? How exactly did you test that?

Comment: I have tested it by calling your function in the "start" function and writing output to the Unity console using Debug.Log

Comment: `void Start()
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            string abc = RandomString();
            Debug.Log(abc);
        }
}`

Comment: Maybe you should only generate one instance of `Random` and store it (See updated answer). You could as well use `Random.Range` if this is Unity specific anyway. I can not explain how this method should always return the same value after a certain amount of iterations ..